# Encountering Error when trying to INSERT INTO an excel file

Tags: c#, sql, excel

I'm trying to figure out how to insert a row of data into an existing Excel file.   The file is simple with ONLY 3 headers,  CITY STATE and ZIP.   I've selected the 3 cells in Excel and named the range Browns.  When I run the program I get an error code.    Number of Query Values and Destination fields are not the same.

This is what I pass into the method

```
Excel_IO.inSertRowTEST(filePath1.Text, "Browns");
```

Methods I've created.

```
public static void inSertRowTEST(string FP1, string TableName)
    {
        string sql = null;
        Excel_IO.openSheet(FP1);
        sql = "INSERT INTO  " + TableName + " VALUES ('Jack','Smith')";
        myCommand.CommandText = sql;
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Excel_IO.closeMyConnection();


    }

public static void openSheet(string filePathMain)
    {
        // MyConnection Equals A New OleDbConnection, The Connection Defines Which Versions Of Excel Files Can Be Used, The file path, And Some Basic Excel Properties
        MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePathMain + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0; HDR=Yes;\";");

        // Opening The Connection With The Excel File
        MyConnection.Open();

        // The Connection Gets MyConnection
        myCommand.Connection = MyConnection;


    }

public static void closeMyConnection()
    {
        MyConnection.Close();

    }
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

### Exact Error Code

---

System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): Number of query values and destination fields are not the same.

at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)

at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)

at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)

at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)

at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)

at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

at MyExcel_IO.Excel_IO.inSertRowTEST(String FP1, String TableName) in c:\Users\t1008ts\Desktop\Projects\MasterP2\May19Template\Excel_IO.cs:line 220

### at MyExcel_IO.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\t1008ts\Desktop\Projects\MasterP2\May19Template\Form1.cs:line 121

### OK

Comment: If you've selected 3 cells, why are you trying to insert 2 values?

Comment: I posted the Error in the question.... I've also posted the exact error...

Answer (score 0):

> I've selected the 3 cells in Excel and named the range Browns

I think when you insert into the excel spreadsheet you specify the table (or worksheet) rather than creating a range.

Try renaming a worksheet to "Browns"

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/rename-a-sheet-HP005202108.aspx